# Laravel Artisan just leaves blank line in cmd

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, migrate

When I run php artisan migrate, it just has a blank line in cmd and then asks me to do something else? Any ideas what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Try adding the `--verbose` option to get more details. I'm guessing its something todo with running PHP on Windows. It can be weird if it's not setup exactly perfect.

Comment: Same issue... I'll try and reinstall xampp, then reinstall composer

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the shell menu built into composer, it doesn't work... Make sure all file explorer windows are closed... the it works :'(